# Is this website only for American politics of for worldwide politics?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, questions

New to this Page.  I would like to know Is it discuss only American Politics or whole over the world Politics?

I would like to ask the following question:

> **Why Politicians pretend Honest but not? Why Powerful Countries interfere or other countries matters? Why they depend on parasitically?**

> Sri Lanka - Rajapaksha regime governed this country more than 20 years. They came into power promising people that they are going to developed this country like Singapore. But today they bring down the standards according to the world ranking middle class to poor. People pleading international community forums like UN/IMF/World Bank/ European Community to support people and ask for the election allowing people to choose the new government. Instead they are supporting this robbers and try to loot our resources by taking the advantage of the current situation. Where is so called star Democracy?

Comment: Hello Sanath, and welcome to Politics.  This is an international forum.  Some notes for new questioners: See [ask].  We **don't discuss**; it is question/answer.  **Avoid push questions**; don't use a question to push a particular political stance or point of view. Do **ask questions that can be answered**;  so "why pretend to be honest" would be a bad question for this site.

Comment: Please post a single Q&A for each question that you have and search before asking, put your question in context and make sure it is about politics and answerable without resorting to opinions only. This is less of a discussion forum and more a knowledge base.  You ask something that involves some kind of knowledge, others answer and give the knowledge.

Comment: Following the edit, this now needs to be migrated back to the main site.

Comment: Questions should not be totally edited to avoid the appropriate system response. If the user has a question that should be on main, they should be asking it on main.

Comment: I've tried to migrate this question back to the main but the system doesn't seem to let me. It might be better to reask the question on the main site. Feel free to reply to this message if you don't understand what that means or if you just need help with the site.

Comment: Do you want me to delete the question here and ask the same in main site?  Then what is the main site? No worries I can do it.  But guide me to the main site.

Comment: The main site is https://politics.stackexchange.com. That's where we post questions about politics. The site you are on right now is https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com, also known as the "meta site". The meta site is the site where we discuss what does and does not belong on the main site. No, you do not need to delete the question here, because it might help future users to better understand what is and is not on-topic on the main site. If you have a politics question, please just post it as a new question on the main site.

Comment: There are some problems with the question:  You say *This bad thing happens, how to stop it?*  This question probably doesn't have an answer.  If there was a simple way to stop the bad thing, then someone would have already stopped it.   This question might not be well received. Remember to ask questions that can be answered. Avoid "pushing" one point of view.

Comment: "Is it discuss" My english is not the best, so posibly I misunderstanding it, but this site is not for discussing politics, it´s for asking questions about it and geting fact based answers. The question must be also ontopic.

Comment: I find this question extremely confusing.  What exactly are what countries doing to what other countries? Which politicians?  What matters?  Give some examples, because right now I have no idea what's being asked.  "Developed nations are screwing poor countries on emissions" - specific.  "Developed countries depend on child labor in country X" - specific.  "Developed countries ignore the ethics of cobalt mining in DRC" - specific.  Then ask a specific question around it.

Comment: You need to post your edited question [on the main site](https://politics.stackexchange.com/). It is off-topic here on Meta. I'm sorry that your first experience has been so confusing but hopefully you'll start picking it up.

Comment: I again rolled the question back from a question for the main site to the original meta-question. Please stop editing it to an actual politics question. I also added the text of the question you apparently would like to ask so we can discuss if it is suitable for the site. Please do not expect any answers here on meta which answer the actual politics quesiton.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, [Politics Stack Exchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) handles questions about politics and political processes pertaining to any country on the globe (and occasionally even about [space](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space)).

However, your example question would probably not fare too well on this site. The reason is that politics stack exchange is not a website for political activism. It's for people who want to learn and teach about politics. It's not for people who want to convince people of their opinions. So:

1. Avoid rhetorical questions (like "Where is so called star Democracy?"). Write answerable questions instead.
2. Avoid loaded questions (like "Why they depend on parasitically?"). A loaded question is a question where the phrasing of the question already implies that someone did something bad. If you want to understand the behavior of a state actor, describe the behavior in a neutral tone.
3. Avoid insulting people you politically disagree with (like "this robbers"). Call them by their name or function or use some neutral term.
4. Avoid saying that someone is evil without proper explanation (like "try to loot our resources"). Explain what exactly you are asking about, so it can be understood by people who are not as familiar with the situation. Links for further information can be helpful. And do so in a neutral tone.
5. If you just post to complain about some political injustice or grievance, **don't!** Politics Stack Exchange is not the platform for this.

Comment: In short I asked from the whole world Sri Lanka economically bankrupt because of one family made economical disaster.  Are there any way to bring them into courts internationally.

Comment: @Sanath that's a question about legal strategy.  It would be off topic even on law.SE.  You can if there are courts or enforcement agencies which handle one type of case or another.  But you should provide details (as much as you can) of the case rather than concentrate on who you think is guilty.

Comment: IMF World Bank conducted investigations and they in there forums directly accused as this is man made economic disaster already they have evidence atha Rajapaksha withdrawn 65 billions from Sri Lanka and invested different countries. Will this not enough for the countries disaster.  I am seek help for whole nation.  because now they are imposing taxes screwing poor people's life.  Is it possible for me to take this question up here or is there any other forum to direct this question.

Comment: @Sanath You can ask questions which help you to better understand the situation and what options there are. But if you are "seeking help", then it appears that you are practicing political activism. That's not welcome in this community. If you want to create awareness for a political problem or even try to mobilize people for a movement, then this is the wrong place. Try Facebook, Twitter or Reddit.

Answer (score -16):

You see, this site isn't about politics at all.

This statement can be interpreted on at least two levels.

First, one needs to differentiate media and policy. All serious discussion about decision making happening among politicians, not in media, it is very difficult in general to hold a descriptive discussion about politics for anyone but insiders. That still not mentioning the problem that even insidres hardly ever know the whole picture because of the overall cultural degradation. No means for that.

Still, in some cases this site can circumvent this limitation, I believe.

But there is a higher limitation that cannot be circumvented here. This site copies the style of StackOverflow, a programming site. However, in programming, there is a different standard of answerability that doesn't suit a social science. It isn't related to knowing something, but it is related to doing something, and for programming that standard is just fine because programming is a practical thing (the site on "work place" or travel or electronics also looks fine, which I think is no coincidence). Still, the format requires the locals to adopt that unhappy standard and kill here anything of value.

Of course, anything of value would have been killed just as well by the power of chaos, so conspicuous on the Internet. Rationality requires maintaining the idea of Good, that is to say a philosophical discipline on the part of free minds. But that is a different story.

Comment: This site is *literally* about politics ....

Comment: @deep64blue Your statement needs a proof, based on observation; just as mine. But you see, your statement looks a little *too* bare. I did provide my observations, regarding the standard of answeribality that does not suit a social science.

Comment: I won't claim to 100% understand what you are getting at - but if the last part is implying that a sense of "good" is lacking from the maintainers of this site - I agree that is the problem. Individuals who fail to accept there is objective truth and good can never produce a healthy political environment or forum. Believing "there is no truth(good)" is itself a truth statement, rendering the entire philosophy invalid.